# im issue CLI command string works in cmd line not with Python sub process

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, mks-integrity

Following im issue CLI command string works in cmd line not with Python sub process :
CLI command working in Command Line:

```
im issues --queryDefinition='((field["Project"]="/L2H0090") and (field["Document ID"]="11601660") and (field["Status_fld"]="reviewed","released","approved") and (field["Category"]="Software Test") and (field["External ID"]contains"Fully_Automated"))'
```

Python Code:

```
import subprocess

string = "im issues --queryDefinition="+'((field["Project"]="/L2H0090") and (field["Document ID"]="11601660") and (field["Status_fld"]="reviewed","released","approved") and (field["Category"]="Software Test") and (field["External ID"]contains"Fully_Automated"))'
try:
    result = subprocess.check_output(string)
    print(result)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)
```

Its showing below error:
`*** The query and queryDefinition options are incompatible with an issue selection.`

I've tried way to input string to the subprocess.check_output.
But every time same output I am getting.
Please support here to get correct command string which shall work in python as well.

Thanks in advance.

string = """im issues --queryDefinition='((field["Project"]="/L2H0090") and (field["Document ID"])=""" + str(TestSuite_ID) + """ and (field["Status_fld"]="reviewed","released","approved") and (field["Category"]="Software Test") and (field["External ID"]contains"Fully_Automated")'"""

Comment: You're generally better off using a list argument to `subprocess` functions instead of a string. If it's a string, use `shell=True` so it will be processed the same as in CMD.

Comment: Same error with shell=True in check_output function. Tried in Popen function as well.

Comment: Show the command you type in the CLI, it sounds like there may be a quoting difference.

Comment: im issues --queryDefinition='((field["Project"]="/L2H0090") and (field["Document ID"]="11601660") and (field["Status_fld"]="reviewed","released","approved") and (field["Category"]="Software Test") and (field["External ID"]contains"Fully_Automated"))'

Comment: This is the working command.

Comment: Put it in the question so you can format it readably.

Comment: Updated in question.

Comment: The CLI command has an unmatched `'` at  the end. Is that really what you typed?

Comment: Yes this command is working

Comment: Strating ' is there before first field

Answer (score 0):

The Python code is missing the `'` around the value of the  `--queryDefinition` option.

If you have a string that contains both single and double quotes, it's easiest to write it by delimiting it with triple quotes, rather than concatenating strings with different delimiters around each part. When you do the latter, it's easy to miss some of the nested quotes.

So copy the command you entered in the CLI, and just paste it inside a triple-quoted string.

```
string = """im issues --queryDefinition='((field["Project"]="/L2H0090") and (field["Document ID"]="11601660") and (field["Status_fld"]="reviewed","released","approved") and (field["Category"]="Software Test") and (field["External ID"]contains"Fully_Automated"))'"""
```

Comment: Thanks, it works like a charm! one more favor @barmar..If I want to add Document ID value in this string externally. How can do it?

Comment: Document ID to be added in string externally. I tried with string added in question but its not working. giving error: *** MKS124814: Cannot show view information: Missing end ) before "

Comment: Use an f-strying if you want to insert variables inside the string. The f-string can be triple-quoted, e.g. `f"""...{variable}..."""`